Unable to redirect the to correct URL after form submission with Codeigntier 4
I am having trouble redirecting to /admin/seo after form submission.  The script insists to stay at https://www.example.com/admin/seo/submitIndexNow.  My form is a simple button as follows:
<form method="POST" action="/admin/seo/submitIndexNow">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

My controller takes my sitemap.xml and preps it for submission to indexnow.  Here is my controller:
<?php
namespace App\Controllers\Admin\SEO;
use App\Controllers\Admin\Admin_Controller;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter;

class SEO_Controller extends Admin_Controller
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function SEO_index()
    {
        $this->data['admin_css']    .= '';
        $this->data['admin_js']     .= '';
        return view('/Admin/SEO/seo_index', $this->data );
    }

    public function submitIndexNow()
    {
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', '1');

        // Path to your sitemap
        $sitemapPath = 'sitemap.xml';
 
        // Load the sitemap
        $sitemap = simplexml_load_file($sitemapPath);
        if ($sitemap === false) {
            return redirect()->to('/admin/seo')
                ->with('warning', 'Failed to open sitemap.xml');
        }
        
        // Extract URLs from the sitemap
        $urlList = [];
        foreach ($sitemap->url as $url) {
            $urlList[] = (string) $url->loc; // Get the <loc> content
        }
        
        // Your API key and key location
        // openssl rand -hex 16
        $apiKey = "[deletedkeyhere]";
        $host = site_url();
        $keyLocation = site_url($apiKey);
        
        // Prepare the payload
        $payload = [
            "host" => $host,
            "key" => $apiKey,
            "keyLocation" => $keyLocation,
            "urlList" => $urlList // List of URLs extracted from the sitemap
        ];
        
        // Convert payload to JSON
        $payloadJson = json_encode($payload, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        
        // Call submitIt() to send the payload
        $this->submitIt($payloadJson);
    }

    public function submitIt($payloadJson)
    {
        // API endpoint for IndexNow
        $endpoint = "https://api.indexnow.org/indexnow";
    
        // Initialize cURL
        $ch = curl_init($endpoint);
    
        // Set cURL options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payloadJson);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
        // Execute the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
        // Get HTTP response code
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       
        curl_close($ch);
        
        // Handle response
        if ($httpCode === 200) {
            return redirect()->to('/admin/seo')
                ->with('info', 'Success - sitemap.xml was submitted to IndexNow');
        } else {
            return redirect()->to('/admin/seo')
                ->with('warning', 'Failed to submit URLs. HTTP Code: ' . $httpCode)
                ->with('response', $response);
        }
        
    }

}

The submission fails which is fine.  Curl has no errors, however, httpCode replies with an error (eg not 200) which is fine but I cannot get the script to redirect back to /admin/seo where I want to display the errors.  I always end up at a blank screen at https://www.example.com/admin/seo/submitIndexNow. I know for a fact that the script handles the HTTP response correctly and get to the redirect portion of the script.  In fact, it gets to the warning part.  If I place something like  echo 'here'.die();  just before the return direct, it works... I just can't get the redirect to go back to /admin/seo. It insists on staying at https://www.example.com/admin/seo/submitIndexNow. Any help super appreciated.
These are my routes:
$routes->add('/admin/seo', 'Admin\SEO\SEO_Controller::SEO_index');
$routes->add('/admin/seo/submitIndexNow', 'Admin\SEO\SEO_Controller::submitIndexNow');


Use your browser's Network dev-tools panel with the "Preserve log" option enabled to monitor the requests. Does it go to /admin/seo but then get redirected again perhaps?

I think you may be missing a return here: $this->submitIt($payloadJson); - should be return $this->submitIt($payloadJson);. Right now your submitIt function is returning a response, but your submitIndexNow function is not, so that's why its not redirecting?
